# General Techniques - Number sets

Tags: contest-math, irreducible-polynomials, irrational-numbers

There are many problems involving, proving numbers are irrational or not an integer and so forth (e.g roots of polynomials, size of an angle)

What are some general techniques/tricks that I can use in these types of olympiad problems?